# Writing help for a custom grails script

Tags: grails, groovy

I am writing a custom grails script.  I want custom help, options etc.

According to doc (
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#creatingCustomScripts), I just need to do:

```
description( "Generates a controller that performs CRUD operations and the associated views" ) {
  usage "grails generate-all [DOMAIN CLASS]"
  flag name:'force', description:"Whether to overwrite existing files"
  argument name:'Domain Class', description:'The name of the domain class'
}
```

However when I add that to my script, I get:

```
Warning: Error caching created help for /server/scripts/ExecuteDBScript.groovy: No signature of method: ExecuteDBScript.description() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, ExecuteDBScript$_run_closure1) values: [Generates a controller that performs CRUD operations and the associated views, ...]
```

My script looks like:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")


description( "Generates a controller that performs CRUD operations and the associated views" ) {
    usage "grails generate-all [DOMAIN CLASS]"
    flag name:'force', description:"Whether to overwrite existing files"
    argument name:'Domain Class', description:'The name of the domain class'
}
/**
 * Script to execute the DB script.
 *
 */
target(main: "This script executes DB Script") {
...
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is poor, but I found this solution:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsBootstrap")

USAGE = """
    grails script-name [PARAM]

where
    PARAM       = Description
"""

target (default: "command description") {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link (http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#creatingCustomScripts) refers to the latest version of grails, a non-stable version (3.0.0.M2).

Probably you are using the latest stable version, 2.4.4, so the correct docs are here: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Command%20Line/create-script.html